# Friend ostream& operator<< can't access private member

Tags: c++, friend

Roughly, this is what my code looks like:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class A{
 private:
   size_t num_;
 public:
   A(initializer_list< something<K,V> > smthng);
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const A &as){
       size_t number = num_;
  };  
};

template<typename K, typename V>
A<K,V>::A(initializer_list< something<K,V> > smthng){

    size_t sz = 5;
    num_ = sz;
}
```

For some reason my code will always give "error: invalid use of non-static data member" as an error when I attempt to compile.  Obviously the code above isn't what I have exactly, but this is the only error I'm getting.  I thought the benefit of using the friend function wasa thaat you can access private members, but I can't seem to do so.

Answer (score 1):

A friend function is an external function w.r.t. the class you are defining it in. You can access private members, but you have no `this` pointer available.

Threfore, you should change

```
size_t number = num_;
```

with

```
size_t number = as.num_;
```

inside the `operator<<()` implementation.

Comment: calling as.num_ within friend results in a segmentation fault

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly initializing the value of the parameter `as`? Using references is not a guarantee that the reference is valid.

Comment: yes, this is a school project, and those are initialized correctly by the teacher

Answer (score 1):

As it currently stands, you are using the num_ variable as if it were a static member variable, that is, as if it does not belong to a particular object of a class but belongs to the class as a whole. What you need to do is to indicate the object whose private member variable num_ you need to access via you << operator. You need to do:

```
class A{

private:
    int num_;

public:
    A();

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const A &as)
{
   int number = as.num_;
   out << number << std::endl;
}  
};

A::A()
{

   int sz = 5;
   num_ = sz;
}

int main()
{
   A object;
   std::cout << object << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

This works fine for me. Try to compile this as it is and you will see it displaying 5 on the console without errors. The segmentation fault is probably due to another error on your code.

Comment: thank you for the comment, but that now results in a segmentation fault